# Paths to execute PHP scripts to connect with servers from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp

Im doing an android app which connects with a MYSQL server to store some data. Using xampp is possible to access to PHP scripts from Android by getting the IP address of the server plus the php file name(the scripts must be in httdocs folder) An example:

192.168.1.1/nameScript.php

My question is...if someone has a server (not using xampp), the path to execute those scripts are the same? I mean, could it be just a random path of the script, without the server IP before?(192...in this case) The connection with the server is done in the php file so I dont know how it works with servers without xampp.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the web address/IP to identify the file you are accessing. With just the `/nameScript.php` your web request will have no idea where its going. You need to properly identify the web portal where the script can be found : example `198.123.1.45/some/path/to/script.php`. XAMPP is for local testing correct? So then you can get away with having it in the root folder, but however when your on a live server you might not have that flexibility either because of server limitations or for better file management.